# Python conditionals without if statements

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I am trying to complete a homework exercise for the following and I am stumped:

> Create a variable called `mark` and assign it the value 65. Then write a series of `if ... elif ... else` statements to assign a new variable a grade such that marks below 50 produce "Fail", from 50 to 59 produce "Pass", from 60 to 69 produce "Merit" and from 70 and up produce "Distiction".
>
> Print the grade.
>
> Then implement the same logic again, but this time without using if statements.

I am able to complete the first part but I am unsure on how to do the same avoiding IF functions - can anyone help?

Using IF functions I have the following which works as expected:

```
mark = 50
if mark > 69:
    print(mark, "marks is a Distinction")
elif mark <= 69 and mark >= 60:
    print(mark, "marks is a Merit")
elif mark <= 59 and mark >= 50:
    print(mark, "markss is a Pass")
else:
    print(mark, "marks is a Fail")
```

I have no idea where to begin for avoiding if functions

Comment: You can use a `while` with an unconditional `break` at the end as a replacement for an `if`. It's silly, but so's the assignment.

Comment: (in terms of how I came to that suggestion -- "where to start" is by looking at the list of flow control operators and thinking about how they could be abused towards your end)

Comment: ...that said, Stack Overflow's scope is limited to _practical_, answerable questions; avoiding something that's manifestly the right tool for the job is anything but practical.

Comment: There are also conditional expressions you can use to set a `msg` variable, which lets you use a single `print(msg)` call once `msg` is set.

Comment: _nod_; chaining short-circuiting flow control operators is certainly an option there too.

Comment: About your first code with if... elif... else: in elif mark <= 69 and mark >= 60: , mark <= 69 is useless since this part of the code will be executed only if mark > 69 is False. The purpose of elif is to avoid worrying about conditions already tested before.

Comment: I hope the teacher isn't expecting them to use a `match` statement...

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can "abuse" booleans to write an algebraic expression for the result: for example, try to print a = "small"*(mark < 50) + "big" * (mark >= 50) for different values of mark.

Comment: I'd use this: https://pypi.org/project/intervaltree/

Comment: (Maybe; it doesn't handle half-infinite intervals, and I'm not sure it handles open intervals well.)

Comment: Indeed that's a weird task, but I bet it's for the purpose of having students think out of the box and research different tools and their uses. In that aspect I'd call it pedagogically worthy. As a former teacher, I enjoy reading the variety of different answers here.

Answer (score 5):

Your current structure is likely the most readable and explicit if using pure Python. Note that you can simplify by only checking one bound as your intervals are successive and non-overlapping.

```
mark = 50
if mark > 69:
    print(mark, "marks is a Distinction")
elif mark >= 60:
    print(mark, "marks is a Merit")
elif mark >= 50:
    print(mark, "marks is a Pass")
else:
    print(mark, "marks is a Fail")
```

That said, if you really want a non-if solution and want to annoy a bit your instructor, what about:

```
mark = 65
grades = ['Fail', 'Pass', 'Merit', 'Distinction']
print(f"{mark} is a {grades[sum((mark >= 50, mark >= 60, mark > 69))]}")
```

Another approach using [`itertools.compress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress):

```
from itertools import compress
grades = ['Distinction', 'Merit', 'Pass', 'Fail']
tests = (mark > 69, mark >= 60, mark >= 50, True)
print(f"{mark} is a {next(compress(grades, tests))}")
```

Comment: Wow, similar idea to mine, but even more elegant and explicit! Upvoting

Comment: @Yevhen not sure I would call this elegant, rather "hacky". I would certainly not use this in production code ;)

Comment: The moment the task states "without using if statement" nobody is talking about production code anymore :)

Comment: I like the 2nd solution; and as I said in an earlier comment, I doubt that will annoy the instructor (unless I'm totally wrong on their purpose).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming list `["Fail", "Pass", "Merit", "Distinction"]`.

If you divide the `mark` by 10 (without remainder) (`mark // 10`) you'd get 5 for 50-59, 6 for 60-69, etc. If you subtract 4 from it you'll get an index of the correct result (1 for "Pass", 2 for "Merit", 3 for "Distinction"). Except for cases when `mark` is less than 40 or more than 80. We can cap the index with `min` and `max` accordingly:

```
mark = 50
["Fail", "Pass", "Merit", "Distiction"][min(max(mark//10 - 4, 0), 3)]
```

It is a very weird solution for a very weird task

Comment: I like it as well (although dependent on the regular pattern) ;)

Answer (score 2):

A bit different approach than the rest of the answers, I limit the index with min/max and get a value from a big list.

```
grades = ["Fail"]*50 + ["Pass"]*10 + ["Merit"]*10 + ["Distiction"]

for mark in [-100,0,49,50,51,59,60,61,69,70,71,120]:
    print(mark,grades[min(len(grades)-1,max(0,mark))])
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll join the fun :) with my solution:

```
mark = 65

print("Fail"*(mark < 50) + "Pass"*(50 <= mark < 60) + "Merit"*(60 <= mark < 70) + "Distinction"*(70 <= mark))

# Merit
```

To illustrate my point that about anything, however irrelevant it seems, can be used, I imagined this other (quite absurd but fun and working) solution (it assumes mark to be an integer between 0 and 100):

```
a="ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffppppppppppmmmmmmmmmmddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd"
print(a[mark].replace("f", "Fail").replace("p","Pass").replace("m","Merit").replace("d","Distinction"))
```